# Mouse Click Triggering Event of Element below Form being clicked

Tags: javascript, css, onclick, mouseevent

I have a submit button (form) hovering over an image thumbnail which allows the user to delete the image as seen below

[image: example of problem]

The thumbnail (img element) also has an onclick event which triggers a popup displaying the image in full size. Unfortunately, when I click the 'x' button (submit the form), the onclick event for the thumbnail image below also gets triggered so that the user is shown a popup before the page is redirected. How can I prevent this?

***Additional Info***

The css for the button is as so:

```
.delete_image_button
{
    position:               absolute;
    top:                    0px;
    right:                  0px;
    z-index:                1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery [stop propagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) function , it prevents events from bubling

Comment: Thank you, yes this worked: <script type="text/javascript">
    $("input").click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
</script>

Answer (score 0):

You can use stopPropagation method for prevent the event from propagating to parent node.

```
$(element).click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
});
```